# Hover over link and div change content

Tags: css

Hover over link and div change content

Hi,
I am having trouble whit some html/css coding. I tried many solutions but no success. I want to hover over first link and one div content to hide and one to show. when I hover over second link one div hide and another appear. this is my code and css:

```
enter code here:

> <body id="tijelo" >
>  
>             <img src="screen12.jpg" id=screen>
>                   
>               
>     <div id="naslov">
>     <h1 id="naslov1">Servis računala i laptopa</h1>
>     </div>
>     
>       <div id="underline">
>        </div>
>          <div class="kontenjeri"> 
>        
>         <a href="servis.html" id="majstor" class="botuni">Servis računala i laptopa</a>
>         <a href="spas.html" id="spas" class="botuni">Spašavanje podataka</a>
>         <a href="mailto:t-men@net.hr" id="poruka" class="botuni">Kontaktiraj me</a>
>               </div>
>     <div id="info" class="uvod">
>         <p id="infop"><span>Dobrodošli na moju web stranicu!</span> <br /><br /> <br /> <br /> Popravci računala, sastavljanje novih,
> servis laptopa,<br /> instalacija windowsa, spašavanje podataka,
> čišćenje računala od virusa,<br />  <br /><br /> <br /> <br /> Više o
> uslugama na linkovima.  </p>
>     </div>
>     
>     
>     <div id="info2" class="prvi">
>         <p id="infop2"> Popravci računala, sastavljanje novih, servis laptopa,<br /> instalacija windowsa, spašavanje podataka, čišćenje
> računala od virusa...<br />    </p>
>     </div>
>     
>     <div id="footer">
>     <p id="footp">© t-men 2017</p>
>     </div>
```

---

css:

```
> #screen{ width: 1000px;
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 200px;
>     left: 465px;
>      }
> 
> #naslov {
>     width: 800px;
>     height: 100px;
>     color: white;
>     font-size: 25px;
>     text-shadow: 5px 0 black;
>     text-align: center;
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 50px;
>     left: 550px;
>     border-radius: 25px 25px 2px 2px;
>     background: linear-gradient(#0f5bea, #0429f2);
>      }
> 
> #underline{  
>     width: 800px;
>     height: 30px;
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 151px;
>     left: 550px;
>     background: linear-gradient(#0057fc, rgba(119, 122, 123, 0.35));
>          }
> 
> .kontenjeri{
>     width: 800px;
>     height: 20px;
>     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 183px;
>     left: 550px; }
> 
> 
> /* #kontejner{  
>     width: 800px;
>     height: 80px;
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 200px;
>     left: 550px; } */
> 
> 
> .botuni{
>     display: inline;
>     color: floralwhite;
>     text-decoration: none;
>     font-weight: bold;
>     text-transform: uppercase;
>     margin: 20px;
>     font-size: 18px;
>     text-align: center; 
>     margin-left: 20px;
>     text-shadow: 1px 0 rgb(14, 4, 255);
>     
>         } 
> 
> 
> 
> .botuni:hover{
>     color: blue;
>     font-family: monospace;
>      }
> 
> 
> 
> #infop2{ 
>     font: 15px Lucida Console;
>     color: white; }
> 
> 
> 
> #infop{ 
>     font: 15px Lucida Console;
>     color: white; }
> 
> #info{
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 270px;
>     left: 630px;
>     width: 650px;
>     display: none;
>      }
> 
> 
>         
> #info2{position: absolute;
>     top: 270px;
>     left: 630px;
>     width: 650px;
>     display: none;
> 
> }
> 
> 
> 
> #footer{ width: 800px;
>     height: 50px;
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 900px;
>     left: 550px;
>     color: white;
>     border-radius: 2px 2px 25px 25px;
>     background: linear-gradient(to top, #0057fc, rgba(119, 122, 123, 0.35));
> 
> }
> 
> #footp{
>     text-align: center; }
> 
> 
> span {font-size: 25px;
>     margin-left: 60px; }
> 
> 
> 
> /* #majstor:hover + #info2{  display:block;}  this doesn't work */
```

When I hover over link "servis računala i laptopa" I want to div "info" hide, and at his place div "info2" appear.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

In your case you can't, because you're trying to manipulate a elements that's not a sibling to the link.

You have to use JavaScript.

Short example of how to do it, assuming the two elements are already hidden with `display: none`.

Plain JavaScript

```
let link1 = document.querySelector('#majstor');  // note: let is better than using var
let link2 = document.querySelector('#spas');

let div1 = document.querySelector('#info');
let div2 = document.querySelector('#info2');

link1.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() { showDiv(div1) });
link2.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() { showDiv(div2) });

link1.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() { hideDiv(div1) });
link2.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() { hideDiv(div2) });

function showDiv(div) {
    div.style.display = 'none';
}

function hideDiv(div) {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}
```

---

There is are two similar selectors: Adjacent sibling and
General sibling.

They both work on the same level in the DOM, so a tree such as

```
parentA
    childA
    childB
    childC
        subChildCA
        subChildCB
parentB
    childD
    childE
```

Allows you to use sibling selectors on the children of your own parent. To put it another way, you can only tell your bothers and sisters to do something, but you can't tell your aunts/uncles, nieces/nephews, and so on, to something

**here is a concrete example of this**

HTML

```
<a id="link1" href="#">link 1</a>
<a id="link2" href="#">link 2</a>

<div id="content1">hello world</div>
<div id="content2">good bye world</div>
```

CSS

```
#content1 { display: none; }
#content2 { display: none; }

#link1:hover {
  color: red;
}

#link1:hover ~ #content1 {
  display: block;
}

#link2:hover ~ #content2 {
  display: block;
}
```

More information about the `~` selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

More information about the `+` selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors